# set google map zoom level after using fitBound

Tags: google-maps

I want to change google map zoom level using setZoom command after I use fitBounds, please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uc5gd/3/)

as you can see, this line:

```
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
```

is causing error, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is going to cause an infinite loop.  Use addListenerOnce so it only happens the first time.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Npu36/1/embedded/result/)

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
 map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
});
```

Comment: thanks but I cannot see any change in zoom level, as you can see zoom level is set by fitBounds, and I want to zoom-in another level, but setZoom(map.getZoom()+1) does nothing, what is the reason?

Comment: thanks geocodezip, you are really a mastermind in google map!, I want to zoom-in one level (after fitBounds) and detect whether my markers are still visible in viewport or no, I use map.getBounds().contains, but I get nothing, can you help me plz?

Comment: please take a look at my new post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780050/detecting-visible-google-map-markers-after-setzoom